# Can we use JMS publisher with AMQP subscriber like rabbitmq subscriber client?

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, jms, amqp

I have a publisher that uses JMS and it publishes the data to a topic (topic A) via AMQP. It uses a message broker called WSO2 message broker.

What I want is an AMQP C++ client which can subscribe to the topic (topic A) that I mentioned above.

As I know in in AMQP concept it has routing keys and binding keys. Exchange types (direct, fanout, topic) are passing messages to a queue when comparing those keys.

But in my case, I have no routing key since the publisher is using JMS (pub/sub method) and what I have is only a topic name.

So how do I subscribe to the topic using C++ AMQP client without having keys?

The broker I am using(wso2 message broker) complaints with ampq0-91,
Since I need to use the c++ clients which supports with amqp0-91. After googling I find out bellow c++ clients.

1. [github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP](http://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP)
2. [github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient](http://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient)
3. [github.com/apache/qpid-proton](http://github.com/apache/qpid-proton)
4. [github.com/apache/qpid-cpp](http://github.com/apache/qpid-cpp)

But qpid proton and qpid cpp is only support with amqp1.0 and amqp0-10 versions.

since I have to choose one of the other two clients. Still, I am finding a proper c++ client.

If someone can direct me to a c++ client which can use with JMS publisher it would be a great help.

Comment: JMS is a set of Java *interfaces* that are implemented by a JMS driver, provided in your case by AMQ, that speak the AMQ protocol to the AMQ broker. What you need is not a JMS implementation for C++, but AMQ's C or C++ API.

Comment: yes. my question was like in AMQ's c++ api needs routing keys and binding keys in order to consume messages. But in JMS we don't provide that. Btw by tracing the tcp packets via Wireshark, I could find that the routing key is similar to the exchange name that we provide in the JMS, and the exchange name is equal to "amq.topic".